# Incorrect result of DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

Let us dsolve that Cauchy problem with 12.3 on Windows 10 Pro:

```
ClearAll[w, z]; sol = DSolve[{w'[z] == -1/2 - Sqrt[1/4 - 3*w[z]], w[1] == -1}, w[z], z]
```

> `{{w[z] ->  1/12 (-2 ProductLog[-((1 - Sqrt[13]) E^(2 + Sqrt[13] - 3 z))] -  ProductLog[-((1 - Sqrt[13]) E^(2 + Sqrt[13] - 3 z))]^2)}, {w[ z] -> 1/12 (-2 ProductLog[(-1 + Sqrt[13]) E^( 2 + Sqrt[13] - 3 z)] -  ProductLog[(-1 + Sqrt[13]) E^(2 + Sqrt[13] - 3 z)]^2)}}`

and a warning "Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information". Both results are not correct as

```
Plot[w[z] /. sol[[1]], {z, 1, 2}]
Plot[w[z] /. sol[[2]], {z, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

show: `w'[-1]==-1/2-Sqrt[13/4]`, making use of `{w'[z] == -1/2 - Sqrt[1/4 - 3*w[z]], w[1] == -1}`, is negative, whereas we see a positive slope at `x==1` in the plots. What is the reason of that incorrect result and how to fix it?

Comment: I have got the result `w'[-1] -> -1 - 1/2 ProductLog[(-1 + Sqrt[13]) E^(5 + Sqrt[13])]`. Nevertheless, from the first glance, it is not clear what reason brought you to the conclusion that the result `w'[-1]==-1/2-Sqrt[13/4]` is wrong? Explain please.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch: 1. Which version of Mathemaica do you use? 2. The results of `DSolve[{w'[z] == -1/2 - Sqrt[1/4 - 3*w[z]], w[1] == -1}, w[z], z]` are wrong since their plots have a positive slop at `x==1`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch: : I make use of `{w'[z] == -1/2 - Sqrt[1/4 - 3*w[z]], w[1] == -1}` to obtain `w'[-1]==-1/2-Sqrt[13/4]`.

Comment: This question is the top of the iceberg. It originates from `DSolve[w'[z]^2+w'[z]+3*w[z]==0,w,z]`

Comment: Certainly a bug that should be reported to Wolfram, Inc.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment--not an answer.

Note that clearing w, doesn't clear w'[z].

DSolve does appear to be giving an invalid solution here. Perhaps, it is picking an incorrect branch.

```
sol = DSolve[{w'[z] == -1/2 - Sqrt[1/4 - 3*w[z]], w[1] == -1}, w[z], 
  z]
```

Gives identical solutions: -(1/12) ProductLog[(-1 + Sqrt[13]) E^(2 + Sqrt[13] -3 z)] (2 +  ProductLog[(-1 + Sqrt[13]) E^(2 + Sqrt[13] - 3 z)]

```
solutions = Simplify[w[z] /. sol]
```

Check ODE

```
Simplify[D[solutions[[1]], z] - (-1/2 - Sqrt[1/4 - 3*solutions[[1]]]),
  Assumptions -> z \[Element] Reals] (*not zero*)
```

I think this qualifies as a bug and should be reported.

Comment: CraigCarter (@ does not work.) :Thank you. You could split it in two comments.